# Another way to show ID in pivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code. Is there another way to show ID in pivot besides what I have? What I have does not look very efficient:

```
create table #salary(
    id int
    , fNAme varchar(10)
    , salary int
);

insert into #salary(id, fName, salary)
values(1,'jim',1000)
    ,(2,'mike',2000)
    ,(3,'tim',500)
    ,(1,'jim',300)
    ,(2,'mike',400)
    ,(3,'tim',250)  

select 'salary' as salary, id, [jim], [mike], [tim]
from (
    select id, fNAme, salary
    from #salary
) x
PIVOT (
    sum(salary) for fNAme in ([jim], [mike], [tim])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
salary  id  jim     mike    tim
salary  1   1300    NULL    NULL
salary  2   NULL    2400    NULL
salary  3   NULL    NULL    750
```

Comment: Looks fine to me... with SQL I recommend not creating problems unless there actually is a problem. If that works then use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alternative approach you can consider *conditional aggregation*:

```
select 
      'salary' as salary
    , id
    , sum(case when fName = 'jim'  then salary else null end) as jim 
    , sum(case when fName = 'mike' then salary else null end) as mike
    , sum(case when fName = 'tim'  then salary else null end) as tim
from 
    #salary
group by id
```

Result:

[image]